# Override Global VPC configuration in function level

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have defined VPC settings for the all the functions globally in serverless yml file and this configurations are applied for all the functions correctly. But now I want to override this in function level (not to have VPC configurations for a single function). Is this possible with Serverless framework.

Comment: Why would you think it's not possible? Have you even tried? It's even documented - https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/.

Comment: @dashmug did you read my question properly? As for the documentation, it's only possible to override global VPC config with another VPC config in the function level. No way to say that I don't want VPC for a single function.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    vpc: ~
```

doesn't work, then you'll have to stop defining the VPC in the provider and define them elsewhere (in the function, or as references or whatever). Or raise an issue in GitHub and see whether anyone is willing to fix it.

Comment: Above is not working and Currently, Serverless don't have this functionality so I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4387#issuecomment-337116499)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds: []
      subnetIds: []
```

Comment: This approach dose not work on subsequent deploys. It only works when the function is deployed the first time. Subsequent deploys will put the function in the VPC defined in the provider section. See https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4387